# What's the function of `$editMode` and `$forceReload` parameter in ProductRepository?

Tags: magento2, product

What's the function of `$editMode` and `$forceReload` parameter in ProductRepository?

If I set `$editMode=true` or `$forceReload=true`, what will happen?

When should I set the parameter is `true` when using the ProductRepository?

---

Below is the codes in ProductRepository:

```
public function get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false)
{
    $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey([$editMode, $storeId]);
    if (!isset($this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey]) || $forceReload) {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();

        $productId = $this->resourceModel->getIdBySku($sku);
        if (!$productId) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested product doesn\'t exist'));
        }
        if ($editMode) {
            $product->setData('_edit_mode', true);
        }
        if ($storeId !== null) {
            $product->setData('store_id', $storeId);
        }
        $product->load($productId);
        $this->cacheProduct($cacheKey, $product);
    }
    if (!isset($this->instances[$sku])) {
        $sku = trim($sku);
    }
    return $this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, if you set either the editMode or the forceReload true, you will receive a fresh loaded model from the DB. Otherwise, you'll just receive a model from the cache.